# How to parametrise shapes such as petals and cardioids?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

Okay for example I want to compute a line integral along the curve described in polar coordinates by $r=\sin(2\theta)$ so I will need to parametrise this curve. (In fact I only need to parametrise one segment of the four total ones as that will allow me to figure out what I want to know.)

The problem is I don't have a clue where to start, only things I know is that $r=x^2+y^2$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ but I don't even know if that is relevant.

Similarly I don't know how to parametrise other curves given in terms of polar coordinates such as $r=1+\cos(\theta)$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please learn from websites like 2dcurves.com  where the axes are marked for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, and that $\sin(2\theta)=2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$.

So...

$r=\sin(2\theta)$

$r=2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$

$r=\frac{2xy}{r^2}$

$r^3=2xy$

We know that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

So, the messy truth is that the function is described in Cartesian form by:

$(x^2+y^2)^{3} = 4x^2y^2$

However we want the parametric form of this, not the Cartesian.

Above, I mentioned that $x(\theta)=r\cos(\theta)$

We are also told that $r=\sin(2\theta)$. So we can substitution this expression for $r$ into our formula for the x-coordinate.

Consequently $x(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)$

Similarly, $y(\theta)=r \sin(\theta)$ We can substitute in the expression for $r$ into this formula to get the y-coordinate. So...

$y(\theta)=r \sin(\theta)$

$r=\sin(2\theta)$

$y(\theta)=\sin(2\theta) \sin(\theta)$

To get the parametric answer to your question, you just switch out $\theta$ for $t$ and call it a day.

Comment: It gives the answer of $r(t)=(\sin(2t)\cos(t),\sin(2t)\sin(t))~t\in [0,\pi /2]$ could you explain where that comes from?

Comment: Right, I should have been clearer in my answer. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to find arc length of circle

$$  x^2+ (y-1)^2 = 1 $$

convert and stick with polar coordinates

$$ r = 2 \sin \theta $$

and also with their derivatives fully, do not look back at Cartesian form.Especially the limits turn out so convenient.